# Make a WPF-UI Element with horizontal and vertical Headers

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, scroll

I need to do something like in the following picture:

[Disposition http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/8721/dispo16042013134903.png](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/8721/dispo16042013134903.png)

The persons(1) need to be frozen when scrolling horizontally and the dates(2) need to be frozen when scrolling vertically. So one can allways say this $Person does ...(4) on $Date.
Also there needs to be additional info displayed for every day the person does something(3).

To how my datastructure currently is:
Person -> Dictionary of Days -> ObservableCollection of what is done on this day (can be multiple things)

How can I do this in a good WPF way? Preferably so I can only set the DataContext to my collection of Person and everything else is done by WPF.

I appreciate your help.

---

Edit:

```
Public Class DispoPersonViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase
    Implements iScheduleOrganizer


    Private _dbContext As infosoftEntities
    Private WithEvents _Person As Person
    Private _DictAZGSchedule As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of Date, DispoAZGScheduleViewModel)

    Public Sub New(ByVal Person As Person, Optional ByVal dbContext As IDBContext 
       'Getting the data for the person
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property AZGSchedule(ByVal dat As Date) As BusinessObjects.AZG.AZGSchedule Implements iScheduleOrganizer.AZGSchedule
        Get
            Return Me._Person.AZGSchedule(dat)
        End Get
    End Property

    'I omit the whole load and initialize and check functions here 
 End Class
```

And

```
 Public Class DispoAZGScheduleViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase


    Private _Person As DispoPersonViewModel
    Private WithEvents _AZGSchedule As AZG.AZGSchedule
    Private WithEvents _lSchedule As ObservableCollection(Of DispoScheduleViewModel)


    Public Sub New(AZGEinteilung As AZG.AZGSchedule, Person As DispoPersonViewModel)
        'initializing the AZGSchedule
        Using CSTeile.MyStack.Push("DispoAZGScheduleViewModel.New")
            _AZGEinteilung = AZGEinteilung
            _Person = Person
            Dim lSched As New ObservableCollection(Of DispoScheduleViewModel)
            For Each sc As Schedule In _AZGSchedule.ListAllSchedules.ToList
                lSched.Add(New DispoScheduleViewModel(et, _Person, Me))
            Next
            _lSchedule = lSched
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ListAllSchedules As List(Of DispoScheduleViewModel)
        Get
            Using CSTeile.MyStack.Push("DispoAZGScheduleViewModel.ListAllEinteilung")
                Return _lEinteilung.ToList
            End Using
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property fc As AZG.AGZErrorCache 'for displaying errors
        Get
            Using CSTeile.MyStack.Push("DispoAZGScheduleViewModel.fc")
                Return Me._AZGSchedule.fc.Result
            End Using
        End Get
    End Property

   'I omit here the whole hookup to my BussinessObjects it would get to much
End Class
```

Right now I "build" the whole thing in codebehind and it doesn't do all I want and its slow to render :-(.

Comment: can you post the code of your object model? more or less you can achieve what you need with a wpf datagrid, but you need to work a bit or in codebehind or with templates in xaml since your datastructure has nested properties, hasn't it?

Comment: I wrap my businessobjects in a Display class and forward some of their properties but i'm not sure whther you'd call it nested

Comment: @Patrick Unrelated, but important: here in `ARGENTINA`, where the native language is `SPANISH`, we have a saying... *"If any developer introduces a single line of non-english text in the project (be it code, be it a comment), then he will be punished by paying for the whole team's lunch."* I would suggest you do the same in the future. Apart from the fact that VB.Net syntax is really bloated (you don't actually notice that until you code in C#), there's no way for non german speakers to have a clue what `_AZGEinteilung.ListAllEinteilungen` means.

Comment: @HighCore If you ever come to Switzerland I will invite you to a lunch ;-). As to why its vb.net and why its German that's an instruction from my boss. But I will translate it for better understanding.

Comment: @michele I'm not sure I gave all you asked for so please say if you need more information or I misunderstood you.